# How to get the user's location from within a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created an extension and I'm trying to get the user's location so I can display it to them.

I've tried adding this code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("ua");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Unavailable.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

But nothing comes up in the extension, any advice? I'm also trying to avoid using the Chrome location API as it is only available on the Dev Channel.

Comment: Are you doing that in a content script or a background page? Is your background page persistent?

Comment: I'm trying to get it working in popup.html, I've added the code to popup.js which should get called when the user clicks a button, but nothing happens. I've tested the button to display the word "test" when pushed and that works, it just doesn't get the user's location

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Declare Permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) page in the documentation lists a special permission for your case:

> `"geolocation"`
>   Allows the extension or app to use the proposed HTML5 geolocation API without prompting the user for permission.

You must use it, because the permission infobar cannot be shown for some extension pages (background, popup).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function successCallback(position) {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    const resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
    resultDiv.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude}, Longitude: ${longitude}`;
  }
  
  // Function to handle errors when retrieving location
  function errorCallback(error) {
    const resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
    if (error.code === error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
      resultDiv.textContent = "Geolocation permission denied. Please allow access in your browser settings.";
      // You can also provide instructions for enabling geolocation in the browser settings.
      const instructionsDiv = document.getElementById("instructions");
      instructionsDiv.textContent = "To enable geolocation access, go to your browser settings, find 'Site Settings' or 'Privacy and Security', and allow location access for this extension.";
    } else {
      resultDiv.textContent = "Error getting location: " + error.message;
    }
  }
  
  // Request user's location when they click the button
  document.getElementById("getLocationButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Check if geolocation is available in the browser
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      // Request the user's location
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
    } else {
      const resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
      resultDiv.textContent = "Geolocation is not available in this browser.";
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="getLocationButton">Get Location</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="instructions"></div>
    <script src="script.js">
        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and also include this in your manifest.json file it is work.

```js
{
    "name": "name of externsion",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["geolocation"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/logo_16.png",
        "24": "images/logo_24.png",
        "32": "images/logo_32.png",
        "64": "images/logo_64.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?